# Importing R markdown to Confluence

Tags: r, confluence, r-markdown

I'm trying to work out a way to post into confluence a R statistical program Markdown file. So far I have converted the markdown to PDF and imported that but I would like to be able to embed the markdown page directly.

Thanks!

Comment: maybe ask the Confluence technical support people for help?

Comment: Yes this was my next point of call, wanted to see if anyone had worked this out first though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use **Markdown in Confluence**, it's quite possible using my free Markdown for Confluence plugin. Get it here: https://bitbucket.org/dvdsmpsn/markdown-for-confluence/downloads

Alternatively, Atlassian have also written a [Markdown Macro](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.plugins.confluence.markdown.confluence-markdown-macro).

Hopefully, some of this will be applicable to **R Markdown**.

Answer (score 2):

[conflr](https://line.github.io/conflr/) package will allow you to publish to confluence from Rstudio or render and upload Rmd to confluence.

Comment: Seems promising, downside is it does not support SSO.[issue](https://github.com/line/conflr/issues/38)

Comment: i currently use it with SSO, just [generate an API token](https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloud/api-tokens-938839638.html)

Comment: Agreed, API token and just following the installation instructions works. This is a great solution to the OP question (the answer, IMO).